# Wordpress migration shows 'Currently Under Construction'

Tags: php, wordpress

When migrating a client's Wordpress installation from GoDaddy to a new server, I am met with a white page exclaiming 'Currently Under Construction' when browsing to the site's home page.  All internal pages seem to work when typed in, and the wp-admin control panel still works just fine.

The site's `siteurl` and `home` remain the same, as the domain is pointing to the exact same address as before.  I've disabled all plugins one-by-one, to no avail.

What could be causing this on ONLY the site's root (home) page?

Comment: Look in your WordPress root folder (not your theme folder) for a `.maintenance` file. If it's there, simply delete it.

Comment: No such luck.  No occurrences of a `.maintenance` file.

Comment: may be .htaccess file is the problem, if you also copied from old server, try to delete and create new one in admin setting and save permalink type again. It will create new .htaccess file. Hope this help ;)

Comment: Same deal.  The .htaccess file it generated was identical.